# count the number of participants registered in a confernece (Property [participants] does not exist on this collection instance)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to count the number of registrations in a conference:

```
        $registrationsCount = $conference->registrations->count();
```

And it works it shows the correct number of registrations in a specific conference. But what is necessary is to get the number of participants registered in the conference, because a registration can have multiple participants associated. Do you know to achieve that?

Example of Db structure with 3 registrations in the conference with id 1. The registration with id 3 has 2 participants associated, the other 2 registrations only have 1 participant.

conferences table:

```
id  name
1   conference test 1
```

registrations table:

```
id    conference_id        user_that_did_registration
1           1                            2
2           1                            2
3           1                            2
```

participants table:

```
id      registration_id      registration_type_id          name      
1               1                   1                       Jake       
2               2                   1                       John
3               3                   1                       Paul
4               3                   2                       Peter
```

Participant model:

```
class Participant extends Model
{


    public function registration(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }


    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
    }

}
```

Registration model:

```
class Registration extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
    }

    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'participants');
    }

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

Conference model:

```
class Conference extends Model
{


    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }
}
```

Dont works like " $registrationsCount = $conference->registrations->participants->count(); ". It shows "Property [participants] does not exist on this collection instance. ".

Comment: Do you have a conference model too?

Comment: I updated the question with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to call the nested collection of collections attribute as method:

```
$conference->registrations->participants()->count();
```

Also, maybe you should pass the foreign key for participants:

```
class Registration extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
    }

    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant', 'registration_id');
    }

    public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'participants');
    }

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
}
```

And Finally, try to add hasManyThrough in your Conference model:

```
class Conference extends Model
{


    public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }

    public function participants(){
   return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Participant', 'App\Registration', 'conference_id');
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that shows "Method participants does not exist.
".

Comment: @John I am not sure if you should include the foreign key also, to pass to participant model

Comment: @John, I have edited my answer. Try with `hasManyThrough()` within  `Conference` model

Comment: Thanks, but it shows the same error "Method participants does not exist.
". Adding that to the Conference model the query stays the same "$conference->registrations->participants()->count(); "?

Comment: @John Maybe you should iterate through registration collection and get count of participants?